# How to reduce space in crystal report detail section?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report. In that I need to reduce much more space in detail section. how to do that?

I tried suppress method.but again it showing same problem. how to solve this ?

Here is my crstal report design and output samples

[image]

**Here is output sample**

[image]

while taking print  it is showing more space . after first report entry , it is showing more space.  indicated using next report in red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

- align the top edge of each item to the top edge of each section
- make the height of each item in each section equal to the height of the shortest item in that section; if you need any field to grow, toggle its 'can grow' property to checked
- set each section's height to match the height of its tallest field
- delete or suppress PageHeaderSection4 and ReportFooterSection2
- does the Supplier ID and associated field need to be in its own section?

Comment: yeah, supplier ID should be in header section.when I do suppress nothing happened in report.the space still exists..