# Spacing in the Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Recently I created reports with multiple sub reports and I got a problem of having a long spacing after the station 7 was added as it can be seen from the report.

I know it is because of the item under the station 7 in the group footer 3 which makes this spacing.

Can any one help to solve this.
[image: Spacing in the station 7 details and onwards]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce space in crystal report detail section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035930/how-to-reduce-space-in-crystal-report-detail-section)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without a screenshot of the design View of both main and subreport.

One hint is that you said 'the item under the station 7 in the group footer' which I interpret to mean you have both a subreport and local fields in one section. you might want to have them in separate sections (even though that means duplicate groups) so you can control the locating of each rather than have them interact and push each other out.

Also, I assume you of course have any unused sections in your subreport shrunk to actual zero thickness(even a millimeter will add up fast with repeated loops through the sections, whereas if you shrink the sections to nothing, it skips them like they were supressed) or actually suppressed or hidden